# Create App Service subscription EMPTY

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

Why are these dropdown boxes empty?
[image: Azure App Service dialog box]
I'm logged in with my Microsoft Account.

Comment: What happens when you use the same Microsoft account on the Azure portal? Are you able to see your subscription there?

Comment: I've just checked MicrosoftAzure -> Subscriptions and I can see there that I have the FreeTrial subscription Active. Account type is set to Admin and there's also a subscription ID xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: do you have the appropriate role to create new resources? for e.g owner, contributor etc..

Comment: Please, don't use MVC6 tags anymore. It's for a future version of ASP.NET MVC based on the old webstack (MVC5). ASP.NET Core is a complete new and incompatible, portable version based on .NET Core. Use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] and/or [tag:asp.net-core] tags instead and your question is more likely to be found by people who can help you with the issue

Comment: Me too i have got the same Issue, whats the possible solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log out of your account on Visual Studio. Then log back in.

It fixed the issue for me in Visual Studio 2017.

One explanation would be that Visual Studio has cached your account info from before you started the subscription. Logging out and back in forces a refresh of this data.
I hope Microsoft fixes this soon as it is not a good first impression (and quite problematic to move forward at all) for trying to use their otherwise excellent platform :).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Restarted Visual Studio and now *Subscription* is showing.